# How to pick the first element of a list in powershell keeping auto-complete?

Tags: powershell

This is the command I am invoking:

```
Get-ChildItem | where -Property name -like *asda* | select -first 1 | $_.Name
```

Obviously this call at the end doesn't work because the `$_` only works for iterable loops. But I want to pick that element of the list and turn it into a object where I can call auto complete (ctrl + space).

How can I achieve that in Powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you try ?

```
(Get-ChildItem | where -Property name -like *asda* | select -first 1).Name
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[JPBlanc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70439729/45375) is effective, but let me dig a little deeper:

For a ***streaming* solution** - where each object being emitted by `Get-ChildItem` is processed *one by one, as it is being emitted* - use a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call with the same [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_simplified_syntax) you're using with the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) (`where`) cmdlet:

```sh
Get-ChildItem |
  Where-Object -Property Name -like *asda* | 
    Select-Object -First 1 |
      ForEach-Object -MemberName Name
```

Note: Alternatively, you could use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) `-ExpandProperty Name`.

---

For a ***more concise* solution** - which involves collecting all `Get-ChildItem` output *up front* - use the following:

```sh
((Get-ChildItem).Name -like '*asda*')[0]
```